# How to get unique result in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table:

```
name        marks

aaa         100
aaa         56
aaa         120
bbb          56
bbb          60

The result should be:
aaa         120
bbb          60
```

ie unique name with maximum marks. Is there any query in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT name, MAX(marks) marks
 from table
 group by name
```